# How mass spec formate and acetate adducts masses are calculated?

Tags: mass-spectrometry

If I look at any tables or calculators, I find that negative ion formate adduct has a monoisotopic mass of `+44.9982` units. If I try to calculate myself, I get slightly different result:

```
H + C + O + O = 
1.007825 + 12.0107 + 15.9994 + 15.9994 = 
45.017325
```

The difference is `0.019`, what is already not indifferent, as usually I calculate with a tolerance of `+- 0.02` units, which means this can cause me miss many hits. I could not find out what may cause this difference.

Later had similar experiences with the acetate, as in tables `+59.013851` can be found, but if I calculate:

```
3 x H + 2 x C + 2 X O = 
3 x 1.007825 + 2 x 12.0107 + 2 x 15.9994 =
59.043748
```

Which means even more, `0.0298` difference.

My question is what causes the difference, and what is the correct wat to calculate these masses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your calculation, you are using the *average molecular mass* of the structure, where atomic masses are based on the natural abundance of all isotopes of the element.

```
H:  1.00794 u
C: 12.01070 u
O: 15.99940 u
O: 15.99940 u
─────────────
   45.01744 u
```

However, for the *exact molecular mass* (or *monoisotopic mass*) of the structure, the atomic masses of each atom are based on the most common isotope for the element.

```
H-1:   1.00783 u
C-12: 12.00000 u
O-16: 15.99491 u
O-16: 15.99491 u
────────────────
      44.99765 u
```

Furthermore, you are missing the mass of the extra electron of the formate ion. The electron mass is $m_\mathrm e=0.000548579909070(16)\ \mathrm u$. Thus,

```
H-1:   1.00783 u
C-12: 12.00000 u
O-16: 15.99491 u
O-16: 15.99491 u
e−:    0.00055 u
────────────────
      44.99820 u
```

Comment: Thank you! I was believing I have already the monoisotopic masses in my table... so I need to look for another table. And special thanks for pointing out the extra electrons should be added.

Comment: And if anybody else needs the monisotopic masses, here is a nice table:  http://www.ciaaw.org/atomic-masses.htm